# NetSuite saved search formula for today's date

Tags: netsuite

I am new to NetSuite formula expressions used in saved searches and I am trying to return a text answer to when a custom field (which is a date) is less than today's date.

```
CASE WHEN ({custentity_fmg_date_tmp_exempt_expires}<(NOW())) THEN 'No' ELSE END
```

Answer (score 6):

NOW is not correct, {today} should be used.

Try this:

```
CASE WHEN ROUND({today} - {custentity_fmg_date_tmp_exempt_expires}) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
```

Subtract the custom date field from date today to check if the custom date comes before the date today. If the difference is greater than zero then the custom date comes before today's date.

Comment: This answer works but it should also work with `{now}` (inside curly brackets instead of parenthesis).  Note that as of the time of this post, both `{now}` and `{today}` return the same date/timestamp.